# iOS Selecting Row in UISplitViewController on First Load

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have setup a `UISplitViewController` in a Universal app. It's mostly working fine but I have one little issue.

iPhone - only works in Portrait and correctly loads the `MasterVC` (tableview)
iPad - works in both Portrait and Landscape

with Landscape it loads with both the `MasterVC` and `DetailVC` present on screen. This is good and I am running the following code in the `viewDidAppear` on the `MasterVC` to select the first row if rows exist:

```
private func selectRowOnFirstLoadIfiPad() {
    if self.firstLoad && UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        if self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count != nil {
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);
            self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
        }
        self.firstLoad = !self.firstLoad
    }
}
```

My problem is if the user starts the application with the iPad in Portrait.

With the `UISplitViewController` the iPad goes straight to the `DetailVC` and the `viewDidAppear` on the `MasterVC` is never run (until the user presses the Back button). Then the `tableView` slides onto the edge of the screen and `viewDidAppear` finally gets run, taking the user to the first row.

How can I avoid this and also load the first row straight away if they start the iPad in Portrait as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you perform your segue, I'm assuming that you are loading a detail view based on the cell selected. If that is the case, try sending an NSIndexPath as the sender object in `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `viewDidLoad` of your master view controller. Then in prepareForSegue(), check if the sender object is of type NSIndexPath, as a segue in a storyboard will be a UITableViewCell class. Get the row from that NSIndexPath and load the content into your detail view.

Then in `viewDidAppear` (still in master view controller), select the row initial row so that it is highlighted.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  // ...
  var initialIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: initialIndexPath)
}

func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  // ...
  var initialIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
  self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(initialIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
}

func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?) {
  // ...
  if (sender.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) {
    // Get row from selected row in tableview
  } else if (sender.isKindOfClass(NSIndexPath) {
    // Get row from sender, which is an NSIndexPath
  } else {
    // Handle a default case
  }
  // Prepare the detail view with the index...
}
```